# How to access value of a specific instance of a class?

Tags: java, class

Let's say we have this class:

```
public class Thing {
    public int myInt;

    public Thing(int x, int y){
    // some code here
    }
}
```

And this other class here:

```
public class anotherClass{
    ArrayList<Thing> thingList = new ArrayList<Thing>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thing thing = new Thing(1,0);
        Thing thing = new Thing(0,1);

        thingList.add(thing);

        System.out.println(thingList); // this prints [Thing@538e82g2, Thing@9g3s1f53]
    }
}
```

My question how would it be possible to do the following in real working code:

```
Thing@9g3s1f53.myInt = 10;
Thing@538e82g2.myInt = 15;
```

If that's not possible, what would be the closest work around?

Comment: This doesn't compile. You've declared `thing` twice.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this? You know that those random hashCodes, ill change every time the program is run, and what matters more than these meaningless numbers is the actual reference to the instance of interest.

Comment: Not sure why you would ever want to do this, but you could use a `Map` where the `key` is the object reference

Comment: @JohnKugelman please keep in mind that this is pseudo-code

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. The things that look like `9g3s1f53` are the objects' hash codes, not pointers/memory addresses or anything similar. In particular, hash codes (1) aren't unique, and (2) can change if the object isn't immutable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what would be the closest work around then?

Comment: @That'sme. That depends on why you're trying to do this. Can you add the "why" to your question?